# Логирование lua в syslog

Tags: linux, логирование, lua

Как напрямую писать логи с `Openresty Lua` в `syslog`?

При установке библиотеки `luasyslog` возникает ошибка:

```
ng-gateway_1  | error loading module 'vendors.lsyslog' from file '/usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/vendors/lsyslog.so':
ng-gateway_1  |     /usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/vendors/lsyslog.so: undefined symbol: luaopen_vendors_lsyslog
```

Подскажите как решить проблему, или какую библиотеку использовать.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Было принято решение писать в syslog сервера на уровне nginx.

В docker-compose в `volumes` добавил bind на локальный /dev/log:

```
- type: bind
    source: /dev/log
    target: /dev/log
```

В nginx.conf, директиве `server` прокинул 2 unix socket-а:

```
# Logging configurations
error_log  syslog:server=unix:/dev/log,tag=ng_trace;
access_log syslog:server=unix:/dev/log,tag=ng_trace,nohostname;
```

Для логирования в lua использую `ngx.log(ngx.ERR, 'Log message')`

Все логи из докер-контейнера пишутся прямиком в syslog сервера.

Answer (score 0):

Openresty не пользовал, поэтому за правильность ответа - не ручаюсь. По приведенным логам ситуация похожа на не согласование версий. Возможно отрывок из [FAQ Openresty](https://openresty.org/en/faq.html) ситуацию прояснит:

> ** Why can't I use Lua 5.2 or later? **
>
> Lua 5.2+ are incompatible with Lua 5.1 on both the C API land and the Lua land (including various language semantics). If as you said there are quite a few people already using ngx_lua + Lua 5.1, then linking against Lua 5.2+ will probably break these people's existing Lua code. Lua 5.2+ are essentially incompatible different languages.
>
> Supporting Lua 5.2+ requires nontrivial architectural changes in ngx_lua's basic infrastructure. The most troublesome thing is the quite different "environments" model in Lua 5.2+. At this point, we would hold back adding support for Lua 5.2+ to ngx_lua. Also, we do not want to create confusions and incompatibilities on the Lua land for applications running atop ngx_lua, as well as all the existing lua-resty-* libraries written in the Lua 5.1 language.
>
> We believe it is better to stick with one Lua language in ngx_lua. Chasing the Lua language's version number has not many practical technical merits (if there were some political ones).

Резюме: смотрите версию используемого Lua